# Redirecting outside of ng-view in Angular using ngRoute

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ngroute

I'm on an Angular project and I'm using the default ngRoute for routing.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'main',
            controller: 'mainController'
        })        
        .when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'account/login',
            controller: "loginController"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
  });
```

When I redirect to the login page, the login page appears as a partial view within my index.html page. However, I want the login form to appear within its own html page (without the headers and footers that exist on the other pages). Is it possible to achieve this using ngRoute, or do I need to switch to using ui-router?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I have the same issue.